# Angularjs create navigation bar for quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, web, navigation

I'm new in Angular and I need to make [Navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHEeE.png) for quiz. Each question has it's own checkbox and when it's pressed, this question's link in navigation somehow changes (e.g. background turns red). So I want to make navigation as link array, but I have no idea how to change each link according to checked checkbox. As I understand it, we have one array, clicking on checkbox we take from this array an item and put it to another array and then this array give to links, but how to write this functions? Any idea?

Comment: Do you have code examples?

Comment: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/FzoV2BR14lNcSHLU1kXi?p=preview) yes, i have. I made directive, tried to combine checkbox and link together

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs

In this lab they are building nearly the same application you are talking about

Comment: mmm it's not what i needed now, but anyway thanks, i found there some usefull information for next steps in my project